# Significant speed difference between two seemingly-equivalent methods of calculating prefix sums with GCC for x86-64

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, gcc, cpu-architecture

I tried two almost identical methods of calculating prefix sums, and found that they have significant differences after being compiled. The compilation option is `-O2`.

Different compilation results led to a 4 times difference in their running time.

The first:

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    unsigned a[5000];
    std::iota(a, a + 5000, 0);
    for (int k = 0; k < 1'000'000; k++)
        for (int i = 1; i < 5000; i++)
            a[i] += a[i - 1];
    return *std::min_element(a, a + 5000);
}
```

The second:

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    unsigned a[5000];
    std::iota(a, a + 5000, 0);
    for (int k = 0; k < 1'000'000; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i + 1 < 5000; i++)
            a[i + 1] += a[i];
    return *std::min_element(a, a + 5000);
}
```

[In Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fd5Mhxarj)

What could be the reason for this exception in the compiler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Don't use "#include <bits/stdc++.h>" it is not standard C++ and use std::array when you can.  So you don't have to repeat 5000 all over your code and can use begin(), end() and size()

Comment: Why not use thousands separator consistently, like 1'000'000?

Comment: Have you verified that the output for both pieces of code is correct? In your first loop you should replace `for (int i = 1; i < 5000; i++)`  with for `(int i = 1; i <= 5000; i++)` (you do less work in the first loop).

Comment: Okay, I didn’t include <bits/stdc++.h> anymore, but the compilation result didn’t change.

Comment: "significant differences"? L5 and L6 are just different names. [rsp-120] has moved to a different location. cmp rax, rcx is no different to cmp rcx, rax when it comes to jne, right? What is the speed difference? Compiler explorer does not output numbers and numbers of compiler explorer are not reliable, because they are VMs.

Comment: Which difference exactly is bothering you? Both assemblies look almost the same, the only differences I can spot are some reordered instructions and section names.

Comment: returning the result in `main`? That's implementation defined behavior. Both of the loops in both programs should be removed by optimizer. The result is always `0`.

Comment: what is "this exception in the compiler" ? Please include all information in the question. Currently it is not clear what your question is

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried to re-create this in c (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0) and verified your observation. I get on my old laptop 9.5k vs 28k cycles per iteration. If I compile with -O3, they are both around 9.4k cycles.

Comment: Maybe you could add the c tag as it does apply to c also?

Comment: FWIW, the newer versions of GCC seem to have this fixed.  GCC12 and 13 both produce the same assembly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 2 we see that GCC has done this,

```
.L4:
        add     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
        add     rax, 4
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax-4], edx
        cmp     rcx, rax
        jne     .L4
```

So accumulating values in `edx`, adding a new element into it and storing the accumulated sum to memory. This is fine, no problems here.

In version 1 we see that GCC has done this,

```
.L4:
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax-4]
        add     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        add     rax, 4
        cmp     rax, rcx
        jne     .L4
```

Here the previously stored partial sum is loaded again, and then it is added into the current element.

That is not good, there is a loop-carried dependency through memory, putting the latency of a store+reload on the critical path. On various CPUs that may be 5 or 6 cycles per iteration. In version 2 the similar dependency goes through `edx` instead of through memory, which is pretty efficient on every CPU, letting the loop execute at closer to 1.5 cycles per iteration. Based on that effect, a performance difference of around 4x is expected.

On some newer CPUs it may not work out so badly, if the CPU can use memory renaming (zero-latency store to load forwarding) in this situation. However, about Intel Ice Lake, Agner Fog writes:

> The fast forwarding does not work in the
> following cases, according to my tests:
> ...
>
> - Read-modify-write instructions

We do have a read-modify-write instruction here so that's probably not good.

For AMD-style memory renaming, apparently the memory operand has to be an exact match (not just the computed address, but the way in which it is specified), which we don't have here, so it's probably not good either.

I don't know *why* GCC would compile the two versions in such different ways. Maybe there is a reason and I just couldn't think of it, but maybe it just happened by bad luck.

Comment: FWIW, the newer versions of GCC seem to have this fixed.  GCC12 and 13 both produce the same assembly.